# Angular select, не выводиться ng-options

Tags: веб-программирование, angularjs, frontend

Добрый день! Изучая Angular наткнулся на одну проблему. Вот небольшая форма

```
<div class="form-container" ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <form>
        <select id="file-type" ng-model="type" ng-options="type as type.type for type in data.types"></select>
        <input type="text" id="file-name" ng-model="name">
        <select id="file-classification" ng-model="classification" ng-options="classification.id as classification.type in data.classifications"></select>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <p>File type: {{type.type}}</p>
    <p>File name: {{name}}</p>
    <p>File classification: {{classification.type}}</p>
</div>
```

Данный пример для первых двух полей работает, но не видит третью. В чем там ошибка?

Вот сам код ангуляра:

```
var app = angular.module('main', []);
function Obj(id,type){
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
}
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        types: [new Obj(1,"type-1"),new Obj(2,"type-2")],
        classifications: [
            new Obj(1, "CS-1"),
            new Obj(2, "CS-2"),
            new Obj(3, "CS-3"),
            new Obj(4, "CS-4")
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в чем была проблема: Ошибка в синтаксисе

Во втором элементе **<select>**

`ng-options="classification.id as classification.type in data.classifications"`

Я забыл прописать `for classification in data.classifications`

И полностью получается

```
ng-options="classification.id as classification.type for classification in data.classifications"`
```

Вот что из этого получилось.

```js
var app = angular.module('main', []);

function Obj(id, type) {
  this.id = id;
  this.type = type;
}
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    types: [new Obj(1, "Type-1"), new Obj(2, "Type-2")],
    classifications: [new Obj(1, "CS-1"), new Obj(2, "CS-2"), new Obj(3, "CS-3"), new Obj(4, "CS-4")]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="main">
  <div class="form-container" ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <form>
      <select id="file-type" ng-model="type" ng-options="type as type.type for type in data.types"></select>
      <input type="text" id="file-name" ng-model="name">
      <select id="file-classification" ng-model="classification" ng-options="classification as classification.type for classification in data.classifications"></select>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <p>File type: {{type.type}}</p>
    <p>File name: {{name}}</p>
    <p>File classification: {{classification.type}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```