# select с ng-options не отображает выбранный элемент

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, html-select

модель списка такая:

```
tarifs = [{_id:{$oid:"5e03f33472222f1f4a91af45"}, name: "новый" }, ...]
```

HTML такая

```
<select class="form-control"
ng-model="router.tarif" ng-options="t._id as t.name for t in tarifs track by t._id.$oid">
  <option value="">-нет-</option>
</select>
```

Модель сохраняю и в базу оно сохраняется как нужно, но вот получаю я обратно из базы

```
{"response": {"_id": "test2", .... , "tarif": {"$oid": "5e03f33472222f1f4a91af45"}}, "total": null}
```

Кидаю ответ в модель и получаю новый элемент списка без метки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"angular": "^1.6", обновил до 1.7

Проблема в том что:

```
> {"$oid": "5e03f33472222f1f4a91af45"} == {"$oid": "5e03f33472222f1f4a91af45"}
< false
```

и track by не работает почему-то.

Comment: "Кидаю ответ в модель" - покажите, как. Потому что если верить приведенному response, никакого `_id.$oid` в нём нет

Comment: @Yaant `t._id` помещается в модель а не `t` и в ответе прилетает та же самая модель, которую только что записали.

Comment: `"tarif": {"$oid": "5e03f33472222f1f4a91af45"}},` это то что должно быть в модели и это то что лежит в поле `_id`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654252/16574 - вот тут тожесамое работает, но у него в поле id лежит число а не обьект.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается `value` в документации это не обозначение синтаксиса, а переменная.

```
ng-options="t._id as t.name for t in tarifs track by value.$oid"
```

Работает как нужно.